# Python Word Guessing Game

Tags: python

I'm making this guessing game to have the user guess a random word from a list. I'm confused about how to create if statements where the user's input is greater than or less than the index of the randomly selected word from the fruit list.

```
import random

fruit = ["blueberry", "grape", "apple", "mango", "watermellon"]
fruits = random.choice(fruit) 

guess = input("Guess a fruit: blueberry, grape, apple, mango, or watermellon: \n")

while guess != fruits: 
  if guess < fruits.index:
    print("-You've guessed low, try again")
  elif guess > fruits.index:
    print("-You've guessed high, try again")
  elif guess == fruits:
    print("You guessed the right number!")
```

Comment: `random.choice()` just returns a value from the list.  Both `guess` and `fruits` are _strings_.  `fruits.index` isn't what you think it is.  You'll need to look up the index in the `fruit` list using `fruit.index(fruits)` (or `fruit.index(guess)`).

Comment: Also, I suggest naming your list `fruits` and the randomly selected item `fruit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compare the *index* of the input to the *index* of the answer. Try it like this:

```
while guess != fruits: 
    if fruit.index(guess) < fruit.index(fruits):
        print("-You've guessed low, try again")
        guess = input("Guess a fruit: blueberry, grape, apple, mango, or watermellon: \n")
        
    elif fruit.index(guess) > fruit.index(fruits):
        print("-You've guessed high, try again")
        guess = input("Guess a fruit: blueberry, grape, apple, mango, or watermellon: \n")

#the loop breaks when guess==fruits and enters the else block
else:
    print("You guessed the right number!")
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to fix your variable names: `fruits` should refer to a group of fruits (names) and `fruit` should refer to a single fruit (name).

```py
fruits = ["blueberry", "grape", "apple", "mango", "watermellon"]
fruit = random.choice(fruits)
```

You can also replace the `random.choice` to a `random.randrange` to get the index of a random fruit in the fruits:

```
fruits = ["blueberry", "grape", "apple", "mango", "watermellon"]
i_fruit = random.randrange(len(fruits))
fruit = fruits[i_fruit]
```

You can now use a loop to check the user input. I'll be using an infinite loop to avoid repeating code:

```py
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a fruit: blueberry, grape, apple, mango, or watermellon: \n")

    # If the user guessed right
    if guess == fruit:
        print("You guessed the right fruit!")
        # Exit the loop
        break

    # Find the guess index in the fruits list
    i_guess = fruits.index(guess)
    
    # Compare the indexes
    if i_guess < i_fruit:
        print("-You've guessed low, try again")
    else:
        print("-You've guessed high, try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do this:

```
import random

fruits = ["blueberry", "grape", "apple", "mango", "watermellon"]
fruit = random.choice(fruits)
fi = fruits.index(fruit)

def ask():
        global gi
        guess=input("Guess a fruit: blueberry, grape, apple, mango, or watermellon: \n")
        if guess not in fruits:
            print("You have entered wrong word would you mind to enter right word again")
            guess=ask()
        else:
            gi=fruits.index(guess)
            return 

while True:
  ask()
  if gi<fi:
    print("-You've guessed low, try again")
  elif gi>fi:
    print("-You've guessed high, try again")
  else :
    print(f"You guessed the right answer, Yes Answer is {fruit}!")
    break
```

This is also going to check if `guess` is in `fruits` or not because by doing this your program will not encounter an error if user typed wrong word or word that is not in `fruits` and additionally your user can type again if typed word is wrong.

Comment: It's more efficient to do `guessIndex = fruit.index(guess); fruitIndex = fruit.index(fruits)` and then compare `guessIndex` and `fruitIndex` instead of calling `.index()` for every comparison.

Comment: @Spencer Would you like to check my answer?

Comment: I had tried to do like you said @PranavHosangadi but it is encountering error if user typed wrong word. So, at last I ended here. Do you think it is "_**efficient**_" ?